# Can a blown furnace transformer cause "hot spots" on the furnace circuit board?

Tags: furnace, transformer

We had a/c installed yesterday. The technicians had to pull out then re-install the furnace. In the process, they blew the furnace transformer. They also showed me some "hot spots" on the circuit board. They said:

1. the hot spots are unrelated to the blown transformer
2. the circuit board should be replaced

Are both of these things true?

We were not having heating problems prior to this. The whole thing is disconnected now while we wait for them to come back and replace the transformer. Thanks for any help!

[image: circuit board]

[image: "hot spots"]

Comment: If the furnace was working before the work, they should have the furnace working again on their dime.  Number 2 is correct, number 1 is iffy being not related, but a blown transformer could cause them.  They are suppose to know how to do the work properly.

Comment: As an electronics engineer accustomed to speaking with "techs" about electronics problems, I can say in general when they say things like "It blew", "It shorted out" or "it fried" etc... rarely do they actually know what happened.   In their world their understanding is usually binary... It works or it doesn't.   Why something electronic fails it takes a forensic effort from an experienced engineer to diagnose why.  So when something electronic stops working, they just say "it blew".   That's enough to satisfy the customer every time  (unless the customer is me and I call them out on it...)

Comment: What I'm getting at (before I ran out of characters) is "who knows"?   The tech doesn't, I don't, and neither does anybody else.   If the board has "hot spots"  (whatever that means), it might be wise to replace it.  ESPECIALLY if there is ANY visible signs of heat-damage (i.e. anything getting brown or blackened).   Or at least get a backup on hand.  You don't wanna lose your heat on January 17th at 2AM (because that's when it's gonna happen!)

Comment: @crip659  Yeah I'm not sure either.  What is a "hot spot".   Did they have an infrared camera and they could see areas getting warm?   Or were things just starting to turn brown?   A photo of the circuit board would help immensely!  It's not all that unusual for certain power components to (over time) turn the surrounding PCB material a little brown.  Quite common really.   If these 'hot spots' are around the power supply and the board is a few years old, I might say the tech could be right.   I know those boards cost $$$$ so it's an uncomfortable situation no matter what.

Comment: if turns of the transformer shorted together, it can indeed cause the output voltage to rise. When the voltage rises, any on-board voltage regulator creates more heat. There should only be one or two hotspots in that case though.

Comment: Thanks for all your input! Just added photos.

Comment: My money is on the board failing, and in turn failing the transformer.  @KyleB the problem is, sending electrical engineers out on A/C repair jobs would really drive up the cost of repairs.  Adam Smith says it's cheaper to send the faulty board to depot repair where all boards with the same symptom can be put in a pile and repaired assembly line style.  China says it's cheaper to trash the board and manufacture another. EPA says it's cheaper to toss the furnace and get a more efficient furnace. They're all correct.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica    Absolutely.  I wasn't suggesting an engineer is needed, and I wasn't dissing techs.  They know as much as they need to know.   I was just relaying my experiences.

Comment: @EHS  I'm not seeing "burnt".   R53 looks like it might have got a bit toasty, but that's about it.  I see nothing that would concern me -- If that board is functional, use it.   Though I still think it wise (and I do same) to have a backup on-hand.  Order it now when you don't need it.  It's not a matter of "if" that board will fail... It's "when".   5-10 years is a life expectancy of such things.

Answer (score -1):

The transformer did not blew up, it had a short and created an ARC. But saying transformer blew up means it suffered a catastrophic event.

Arc is uncontrolled amount of current that overload the device, and anything connected to it.

So the output side of the transformer that goes to the PCB could have gotten hit by Voltage spike and too much current creating dark spots (overload) on the PCB (top right corner).

The function of your transformer was to take 120 Volt and covert it to PCB circuit need (probably 24 or 12 Volt). The short in transformer (ARC) would have passed the 120 Volt directly to the secondary transformer side.

However, since the spots are not Black, but light brown, that would be normal and the PCB would be still alive.

Comment: alternatively, some parts of some circuit boards are designed to get a bit hot which can discolour them. It doesn't look like any unusual damage to me. It's slightly darker green, not black.